# Which setting prevents folds from automatically folding on save?

Tags: neovim, folding

in my init.rc I have the following:

```
autocmd BuffWrite *.* mkview
autocmd BuffRead *.* silent! loadview
```

In my init.lua I have:

```
vim.opt.foldmethod = 'marker'
```

In my working files I use the following blocks to create folds:

```
// Header {{{1


***This is the foldable area***


// }}}
```

The problem I have is that everytime I add code to a foldable area and save it, the foldable area folds automatically. This is particularly annoying when I have multiple levels of folds. Because they all fold automatically on save.

How do I prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same behavior with RestructuredText (rst) files with the [RIV](https://github.com/gu-fan/riv.vim) vim plugin.

RIV adds an `au! BufWritePost <buffer>  call riv#fold#update()` that collapse all folds when a file is saved/written.
To disable this feature, add the following to your `.vimrc`.

```
let g:riv_fold_auto_update=0
```